# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer funcionar um programa já existente. Corrigi algumas partes desse programa que me parece foi desenvolvido para a Vers. 2.x, mas eu estou tentando rodá-lo na 3.6.5. Porém me deparei com uma linha que não consigo avaliar se existe erro de sintaxe ou o que seria.

Trata-se da linha abaixo:

```
''' % (args.var, args.mexe.split(os.sep)[-1], mexe.replace('\n', ''), args.iexe.split(os.sep)[-1], iexe.replace('\n', ''))
```

Que gera esse erro: -->

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Desde ja agradeço por alguma colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é uma formatação de string? Substitua o operador % pela função .format()

'{} {} {} {} {}'.format(args.var, args.mexe.split(os.sep)[-1], mexe.replace('\n', ''), args.iexe.split(os.sep)[-1], iexe.replace('\n', ''))

Comment: Substitui a sua sugestão pela linha q estava la e dai aconteceu isso --> "SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal" acusando o erro numa linha depois do final do programa.  Como não tenho experiência com o Python e tb sou novato aqui não sei como proceder.  Será que eu poderia publicar o código inteiro aqui p/ vc ou algum outro colaborador possa entender melhor o problema ?

Comment: Pode sim, vai ser melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Do python2  para o python3 as strings mudaram a representação de um array de bits para o array unicode.

Provavalmente o seu código quer um array de bits e não de unicode que é o formato padrão de  string no python 3.